# Create dummy content

Tags: contentful

Using a free Contentful account I've created a New Space and a Content model named Post. Each Post can have a variety of data types for field

[image: Contentful data types field]

and the one's I'm using are

- title - Text (short)
- subtitle - Text (short)
- author - Text (short)
- slug - Text (short)
- image - Media
- content - Rich text

[image: Contentful Post Content Type]

Now, when it comes to the creation of content, I can add Posts manually by filling out the information in the following form and clicking the green button "Publish".

[image: Contentful Post]

While this is ok if I'm creating one post, if I want to create 50 posts that'd take too long (even duplicating the Posts because they become Drafts and need to still be duplicated, slightly edited and published). How can this be automated?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Contentful DevRel here.

To create a lot of entries and new data we provide [the Content Management API (CMA)](https://www.contentful.com/developers/docs/references/content-management-api/). This API's purpose is to perform WRITE operations in your Contentful space.

One way to create hundreds of new entries you can use this WRITE API and write a custom script to create all of them.

For example [in Node.js that could look like follows:](https://www.contentful.com/developers/docs/references/content-management-api/#/reference/entries/entry/create-update-an-entry/console/js)

```
// Call this in a loop 
client.getSpace('<space_id>')
.then((space) => space.createEntryWithId('<content_type_id>', '<entry_id>', {
  fields: {
    title: {
      'en-US': 'Entry title'
    }
  }
}))
.then((entry) => console.log(entry))
.catch(console.error)
```

If you don't want to define the ID yourself you can use [`createEntry`](https://github.com/contentful/contentful-management.js/blob/a743fbd7e57870a9ec0ae49912bf29b8c4ee07aa/lib/create-space-api.ts#L498-L507). (I just figured the docs are missing that one and will fix it ).

---

Another way to approach this would be to not use the "vanilla CMA". We provide tooling to e.g. import/export all the data that you have in your Contentful spaces. These tools of the ecosystem sit on top of the CMA and abstract the API calls away.

There is [import/export tooling](https://github.com/contentful/contentful-import) that you can use as a provided npm package or CLI tooling. This tools can be useful if you don't want to write a script in your programming language of choice.

What you could do is to [export a space to a JSON file](https://github.com/contentful/contentful-cli/tree/master/docs/space/export) and then adjust the JSON file with the entries that you want to create. You could then use [the `import` command](https://github.com/contentful/contentful-cli/tree/master/docs/space/import) to create a bulk of entries based on the JSON file.

```
contentful space export
# adjust the content file
contentful space import --content-file <file>
```

---

I hope that helps, let me know how it goes. :)

Comment: What if you need to upload thousands upon thousands of entries - will the CLI tool handle that?

Comment: Also, if we do it by adding a giant json all at once, by editing the exported json, won't all the "createdAt" / "updatedAt" fields be all incorrect - or does the CLI manage that... because if we just want to bulk update content and not have to deal with all the updated/created fields....... ur thoughts?

Comment: If you create a JSON file, that the Contentful CLI can consume it'll handle thousands of entries just fine (it'll take a while though). And regarding dates, you're correct `createdAt` and `updatedAt` will be the creation date. If you rely on correct dates you should use a date field for this.

Comment: Thanks Stefan. Is there a process in which I only want to add, lets say 10 entries only. Will the API "insert" those updates in place? I don't want to "override" what is up in contentful, just append more "entries"? Can I just create a json of "entries" only, and only those 10 I speak of?

Comment: The CLI was designed for complete import/export actions. For specific cases, you're better off using the vanilla CMA script using a programming language of your choice.

Comment: Thanks - excuse my ignorance, "is" there a CMA script for node perchance? I can modify to my needs. I only ask because you mention "the vanilla", so I'm assuming there might be something already in play. Thanks again.

Comment: All CMA endpoints are accessible using the client library of choice. E.g. here's the example shown how to fetch entries using the CMA with Node.js https://www.contentful.com/developers/docs/references/content-management-api/#/reference/entries/entries-collection/get-all-entries-of-a-space/console/js

Comment: Stefan, is there a way to "publish" all imported entries given a command. I am running this command, and my entry is imported .. BUT not published... what if I have thousands, I have to singly run a thousand curl commands? How can I just publish everything I use this with? "contentful space import --config config.json"

Comment: There's a "bulk" action. https://www.contentful.com/developers/docs/references/content-management-api/#/reference/bulk-actions/publish-bulk-action/publish-bulk-action/console/js But disclaimer, I left Contentful a few months ago there might be better ways by now. :)